# Laravel Passport 'App\\User' not found?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

My '**User**' model is inside '**App\Models\User.php**', and when I do this:

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
        'username'      => $data['username'],
        'password'      => $data['password'],
        'client_id'     => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'grant_type'    => 'password'
      ]
    ]);
```

Iam getting this error:

```
"message": "Server error: `POST http://localhost/oauth/token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:\nClass 'App\\User' not found\n",
```

It seems Passport is looking for '**User**' model inside '**App**' directory, not the '**Model**' directory which is the right place.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Make sure you update your user Model in `config/auth.php` to `App\Model\User` and run `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `config/auth.php` file search for the `providers` key and change the model from `App\User::class` to `App\Model\User::class`:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Model\User::class, // <-- this line
    ],

    //
],
```

Then delete the configuration cache via `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the model class name in your `config/auth.php` file:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
]
```